# Remove Margin from Inside an SVG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jsx

I have this react component with an SVG icon. Here's what it looks like. I've added the 1px white border around it so you can see where the svg stops:

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of empty space vertically to the right of the icon, inside the svg. I've highlighted the empty space in magenta here:

[image]

I've tried editing the viewbox parameters different ways but I haven't figured out how to fix this yet.

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from "react";

function SvgTelephoneIcon(props) {
    const {iconwidth, iconheight, color} = props;
    return (
        <svg
            width={iconwidth}
            height={iconheight}
            viewBox="0 0 28 20"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            {...props}
        >
            <path
                d="M16.25 18.125h-.106C3.863 17.419 2.119 7.056 1.875 3.894A1.875 1.875 0 0 1 3.6 1.875h3.444a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 1.162.788L9.156 5a1.25 1.25 0 0 1-.275 1.35L7.55 7.694a5.856 5.856 0 0 0 4.737 4.75l1.357-1.344A1.25 1.25 0 0 1 15 10.844l2.356.944a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 .769 1.162v3.3a1.875 1.875 0 0 1-1.875 1.875Zm-12.5-15a.625.625 0 0 0-.625.625v.05c.288 3.7 2.131 12.45 13.087 13.075a.625.625 0 0 0 .663-.587V12.95l-2.356-.944-1.794 1.781-.3-.037C6.987 13.069 6.25 7.631 6.25 7.575l-.037-.3 1.774-1.794-.937-2.356h-3.3Z"
                fill={color}
            />
        </svg>)
}
export default SvgTelephoneIcon;
```

How can I remove the empty space that is highlighted in magenta in the second image above?

Comment: Try using a different viewBox. Please try `viewBox="0 0 20 20"`. Also make sure that the iconwidth and the iconheight are preserving the aspect ratio. In the case you are using `viewBox="0 0 20 20"` the iconwidth and the iconheight must have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with css adding a `className='fill-container`' to the svg and add a rule`.fill-container{width:100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with [this info](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox) on the ViewBox coordinates:

> x - specify the minimum x coordinate
>
> y - specify the minimum y coordinate
>
> width - width in user coordinates/px units >
>
> height - height in user coordinates/px units

I used `viewBox="2 -1 16 22"`

Here is the updated svg, again with a white border around the svg.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I changed the view box and it worked for me:

```
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
```